# Perform NSLOOKUP by reading it from one csv and writing it to other csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, nslookup

I have been trying to do NSLOOKUP and write the values to a csv file.

My file1.csv:

```
Hostname  
abc1  
def2  
fgh3   
.  
.  
.  
and so on
```

I want to do nslookup on these hostnames and write the FQDN to file2.csv like this:

```
Hostname FQDN  
abc1 abc1.na.edu  
def2 bcd2.sa.edu  
fgh3 fgh3.ea.edu  
.  
.  
and so on
```

This is my code:

```
import socket
import csv
name = []
with open('file1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
 reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

for line in csvinput:
 name = socket.getfqdn(line)
 with open('file2.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvoutput:
  fieldnames = (['Hostname', 'FQDN'])
  output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
  output.writerow(fieldnames)
  output.writerow([name])
```

I am only able to get one fqdn of one random hostname in the output file. Although, when I use only 'print(name)' it gives me all the FQDN's in the console. I know i am missing something, please help!!

Made some changes in the code:

```
import socket
import os
import csv
name = {}
CI = {}
with open('file1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)

    # status = [row['FQDN'] for row in rows]

    for rows in reader:
        CI = rows['CI_Name']
        name = socket.getfqdn(CI)
        with open('file2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
                output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
                #fieldnames = ['CI_Name', 'FQDN']
                #output = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                #output.writerow(rows)
                output.writerows([[CI] + [name]])
```

I am able to print the Name and the corresponding FQDN, But can't print the header on the csv column, that is 'CI_Name' and 'FQDN'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import socket
import os
import csv
name = {}
CI = {}
with open('file1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)

    # status = [row['FQDN'] for row in rows]

with open('file2.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvoutput:
    fieldnames = ['CI_Name', 'FQDN']
    output = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    output.writeheader()

for rows in reader:
    CI = rows['CI_Name']
    name = socket.getfqdn(CI)
    with open('file2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
       output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
       output.writerows([[CI] + [name]])
```